# Save my work when trying to rewrite history

Tags: git

I'm new to git. I was working on a new feature of my code on a branch and then I realized I did bad commits that were reflected on BitBucked.
I would like to reset the tree history because I'm the only one working there and it would be much clear but I do not want to lose the code I'm currently working on.

I was thinking if I could do the following:

```sh
git stash                            # to keep my current code
git reset --hard $hash               # to go back to a specific commit
git stash pop                        # to recover my changes
git push --force origin master       # To overwrite the tree.
```

I was also thinking If I could use `git reflog`

These commands would be okay for this purpose?

Comment: `--force-with-lease` is a bit safer than `--force` alone, but otherwise yes. It would have been fine to write as a self-answer (if only in hindsight)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it would be done that way. Note that popping the stash before pushing has no effect, as only commits are pushed.

You can do the push without a local reset too:

```
git push -f origin <hash>:master
```

to overwrite the remote master with the specified hash. This would avoid stashing your changes. Afterwards, you can stash and reset/switch to this commit or reset your local branch(es).

Comment: Thank you for the fast response! And what if I just want to delete a specific commit, f.e, I've 5 commits and I just want to delete the third one but keeping the others. Is that possible? I would use "git revert" but I want to delete it from remote tree

Comment: @paugarreina in that case, you would want to do an [interactive rebase](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#Documentation/git-rebase.txt--i) and drop the commit from your history.